# QGIS Plugin - Runtime Error - R6025

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, runtimeerror

I get an Runtime Error using my QGIS-Plugin after inserting following code

```
if mapType == 0:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)
```

The entire Error-Message is:

[image]

Comment: Is one of those lines causing the error? Or either of those lines? what version of QGIS? Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: Was solved after complete shutdown of computer... Probably an Issue with some globally set variables.. I don't know Now it workes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is QGIS 3 it should be:

```
if mapType == 0:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer1)
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)
```

For QGIS 2, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you for the QGIS3 Solution! Will be used in a near upgrad to the new system